# React Native app won't fetch api data

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch-api

My React Native app won't fetch or get api data. It will not console log data or even an error. I've tried using fetch and axios.

fetch method:

```
    export default class List extends React.Component {
      commponentDidMount() {
        fetch(URL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }
```

axios method:

```
    export default class List extends React.Component {
      commponentDidMount() {
        axios.get(URL)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      } 
    }
```

I'm not sure what the problem is and I can't find a solution online.

Comment: Spelling error in `commponentDidMount()`. It is `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do check spelling function **componentDidMount** 
And try below sample code I have.

```
componentDidMount() {
  let URL = `https://...`;

  fetch(URL)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
      console.log('response:', res.data);
  });
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I get Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): when i use the above code with a lorum ipsum api.

Comment: U should share your source code, if we could check n correct it as possible.